# ListView on Xamarin Forms only shows data when you resave the xml page... Any idea?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Well, I'm working on a Project on Xamarin forms where I drag data from SQL through an API, which is connected to my application. The API works fine, it shows the information from SQL, and then on the `ViewModel.cs` and I can see the data con my `ListView ItemSource={binding path}`, but when the process is completed it doesn't show any data or info. It only displays once I hit <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> on my xaml page.

ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CompraCoba}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SelectionMode="None" MinimumHeightRequest="100" HeightRequest="325" HasUnevenRows="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

                <Grid RowSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Margin="10,10,10,0" HorizontalOptions="Start" x:Name="SucDlr" Text="{Binding monedaC}" FontSize="10" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                    <Label Margin="10,10,10,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="MontoDlr" Text="{Binding valorC}" TextColor="White" FontSize="10" VerticalOptions="Start"  Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Label Margin="10,10,10,0" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="CambioDlr" Text="{Binding diaC}" TextColor="White" FontSize="10"  VerticalOptions="Start"  Grid.Column="2" />
                    <!--<Label Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BackgroundColor="#bababa" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" />-->

                </Grid>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code-behind where vm = to my ViewModel. The GetCoba is an http request, it works fine

```
public ComprasTaxa()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
    vm.GetCoba(1);
}
```

Any suggestion would be an excellent help. Thanks in regards

ViewModel

````
public async void GetCoba(int dias)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var accessToken = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["token"];
                //Get Request
                var url = "https://masterxserver.azurewebsites.net/api/CompraTaxa/GetCoba?dia=" + dias + "";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var CompraTaxaList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompraTaxaM>>(result);


                CompraCoba = new ObservableCollection<CompraTaxaM>(CompraTaxaList);
            }
        }
        ObservableCollection<CompraTaxaM> _compraCoba;

        public ObservableCollection<CompraTaxaM> CompraCoba
        {
            get
            {
                return _compraCoba;
            }
            set
            {
                _compraCoba = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }```
````

Comment: where is the code for your ViewModel?

Comment: Share us the code of your viewModel and did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM?

Comment: I just upload it, the list view only appears when saving de xml page

Comment: And yeah, the INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented on my model and the PropertyChanged() is below my code

Answer (score 0):

From your code and the description of the issue, it seems that the `CompraCoba` set is not notifying the View about the changed property. You mentioned that the VM implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, could you please show that code?

Also, it's possible that after you set value for the `CompraCoba` property, something can override, I would add a `Debug.WriteLine` and printing the value to be assigned and (important) thread it's assigned from (`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`) and make sure you get this print only once and only from the main thread (#1). The fact that the data is loaded on Ctr+S means that property content is most likely correct but the thread it's been assigned from (or PropertyChanged event) is not.